# Problem after installing Magento 2 Module

Tags: magento, magento2

Problem after installing Magento 2 Module

```
{"0":"Please upgrade your database: Run \"bin\/magento setup:upgrade\" from the Magento root directory.\nThe following modules are outdated:\nMageplaza_Osc data: current version - none, required version - 2.1.8","1":"<pre>
        #1 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000027a6560e000000003be33d23#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n
        #2 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000027a6560e000000003be33d23#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n
        #3 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000027a6560e000000003be33d23#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:137]\n
        #4 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n
        #5 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n
        #6 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#0000000027a6567c000000003be33d23#) called at [index.php:39]\n<\/pre>","url":"\/admin\/cms\/block\/index\/key\/217e2153035ab5a787197eadf29e158a213eab4011673d6a912ec463dd32f224\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/315855/51548

Answer (score 1):

"Please upgrade your database: Run ..." means that there is a module registered in the component registrar (`Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar`) (either in `app/code/` or `vendor/`) which may not be found in the `setup_module` table or the row in the `setup_module` table associated with that module contains an outdated version.

In the `setup_module` table there are 3 columns, the `module`, `schema_version` and `data_version` column. `schema_version` and `data_version` are compared to the module registered in the component registrar. If these do not match the "Please upgrade your database: Run..." message is outputted.

I recommend looking in `Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator::beforeDispatch(FrontController, RequestInterface)` to get to know more about the comparisons with `schema_version` and `data_version`.

In short, to resolve the error you're getting you should run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` which will update your database according to various install / upgrade scripts, data / schema patches and `db_schema.xml` configurations.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the Magento module it always disables by default.

You can run below command from your setup root path via terminal or ssh console

`bin/magento module:status` it will show the newly installed module in the disables list in your case it was Mageplaza onepage checkout module and display named as `Mageplaza_Osc`after running this command.

to enable the module you can use the below command.

`bin/magento module:enable Mageplaza_Osc` and then fire below command.

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

setup upgrade will run upgrade command then the module will register the current install version and install require DB update and it only promotes this again when you installed a newer version of the module as in that case if there is any database related change so they can perform as well.

Answer (score 0):

Find your module version in the database with

```
SELECT * from setup_module WHERE module_name="Mageplaza_Osc"
```

Then edit associated columns with the correct version.

### Alternate solution

Find your module version in the database with

```
SELECT * from setup_module WHERE module_name="Mageplaza_Osc"
```

Delete the row.

Then `bin/magento se:up`.